# Credit card validity check

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x

I want to go more in depth, but this is the 'boilerplate'.

Is there any way I can optimize this or use more idiomatic Python code?

```
#Luhn algorithm - distinguish valid numbers from mistyped or incorrect numbers.
def checkNumber(cc_number=''):
    sum_ = 0
    parity = len(cc_number) % 2
    for i, digit in enumerate([int(x) for x in cc_number]):
        if i % 2 == parity:
            digit *= 2
            if digit > 9:
                digit -= 9
        sum_ += digit
    return sum_ % 10 == 0

def main():
    number = input('Input credit card number: ')

    if 12 < len(number) < 17:
        first_two = number[0:2]
        first_four = number[0:4]

        vendor = None
        if number[0] == 4:
            vendor = 'Visa'
        elif number[0] == '5' and '0' < number[1] < '6':
            vendor = 'Mastercard'
        elif number[0] == '6' or first_four == '6011':
            vendor = 'Discover'
        elif first_two in ('36', '38'):
            vendor = "Diners Club"
        elif first_two in ('34', '37'):
            vendor = 'American Express'

        if vendor is not None:
            if checkNumber(number):
                print(f'This is a valid {vendor} credit card!')
            else:
                print(f'This is not a valid {vendor} credit card.')
        else:
            print('Unknown vendor.')
    else:
        print('Sorry, this is not a valid credit card number!')



print(checkNumber('12345'))
```

Comment: The code looks awfully duplicate of the one on wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luhn_algorithm#Python

Comment: @MasonBose Welcome to Code Review! it appears you have [a registered account](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/177192/mason-bose) (as evidenced by [the suggested edit](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/102072)), which can be merged with your unregistered account. You can use the [contact SE page](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/contact) and request the accounts be merged.

Answer (score 4):

Welcome to Code Review. A few basic pointers about programming in python:

1. Go through the code style guide as documented [in PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).
2. Instead of putting comments, make use [of docstrings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/).
3. Use [test framework](https://devdocs.io/python~3.6/library/unittest) for writing a few tests, and use `assert`s instead of `print()` for checks and validations.

---

From the PEP-8 rules:

- Convert the comment about Luhn's algortihm into a docstring.
- Variables and functions are named using `snake_case` convention.
- No unnecessary blank lines are needed. Keep the code clean and concise.

---

Your `main` function can be broken further, into `get_provider`, `valid_card_number` and the one your already have `check_number`. It is completely your choice if you want to raise an exception in case of wrong inputs or whether the functions should return falsy values.

Instead of having an approximately 10 line of code inside if-statement, deal with the else clause first, and return early.

While you didn't actually write the `check_number` code, I'll just put my views about that as well here.

Using a list comprehension, with the help of `% 9` (\$ \mod 9 \$), you can make it quite pythonic. You can then have a `sum(<list comprehension>) % 10 == 0` as a one-liner.

```
sum(digit * 2 % 9 if i % 2 else digit for i, digit in enumerate(map(int, cc_number[::-1]))) % 10 == 0
```

Answer (score 1):

just sometimes some expressions can be assigned to a variable to prevent recalculation like number[0] can be replaced with first_num

from

```
if number[0] == 4:
        vendor = 'Visa'
    elif number[0] == '5' and '0' < number[1] < '6':
        vendor = 'Mastercard'
    elif number[0] == '6' or first_four == '6011':
        vendor = 'Discover'
```

to

```
first_num = number[0]
if first_num == 4:
        vendor = 'Visa'
    elif first_num == '5' and '0' < number[1] < '6':
        vendor = 'Mastercard'
    elif first_num == '6' or first_four == '6011':
        vendor = 'Discover'
```

also, better snake_case in python than CamelCase

from

```
def checkNumber(cc_number=''):
```

to

```
def check_number(cc_number=''):
```

also, sum can be replaced by a synonym to avoid in-bilt clash thus no need of _

from

```
sum_ = 0
```

to

```
total = 0
```

Comment: `sum` is still a library function: https://devdocs.io/python~2.7/library/functions#sum

Comment: @hjpotter92 ammended